# annotation value not of an allowable type rrror : illegal initializer for int

Tags: java, android, annotations

can some please tell me how to fix the issue with this code when i try to compile it  **error: annotation value not of an allowable type** showsup at line 9

here is the code

```js
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String APP_LINK = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;

    static final String KEY_COLOR_1 = "COLOR_1";
    static final String KEY_COLOR_2 = "COLOR_2";
    static final String KEY_COLOR_3 = "COLOR_3";
    static final String KEY_COLOR_4 = "COLOR_4";
    static final String KEY_COLOR_5 = "COLOR_5";
    @BindView ({R2.id.view_1, R2.id.view_2, R2.id.view_3, R2.id.view_4, R2.id.view_5})
    View[] views;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public static SettingsFragment instance() {
        return new SettingsFragment();
    }
```

Comment: @change `@BindView` to `@BindViews`

Comment: @BishoyAbd another error shows up error: element value must be a constant expression

**public class ColorPickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String KEY_INDEX = "INDEX";
    public static final String KEY_COLOR = "COLOR";
    @BindViews(R.id.picker)
    ColorPicker colorPicker;
    @BindViews(R.id.svbar)
    SVBar svBar;
    @BindViews(R.id.btn_save)
    Button btnSave;**

Answer (score 2):

when its multipme use bindviews not bindview

R.id.view_1 not R2.id.view_1

i'm not sure what R2 is.

Use it like this :

```
@BindViews({R.id.view_1, R.id.view_2, R.id.view_3, R.id.view_4, R.id.view_5 })
List<View> myViews;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i changed '@Bindview' to '@Bindviews' but another error shows up here

**public class ColorPickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String KEY_INDEX = "INDEX";
    public static final String KEY_COLOR = "COLOR";
    @BindViews(R.id.picker)
    ColorPicker colorPicker;
    @BindViews(R.id.svbar)
    SVBar svBar;
    @BindViews(R.id.btn_save)
    Button btnSave;**

**error: element value must be a constant expression**

Comment: if its one element use bindview, if its 2 or more in a list use bindvews

Answer (score 0):

first change `@BindView` to `@BindViews`

```
@BindViews({R.id.view_1, R.id.view_2, R.id.view_3, R.id.view_4, R.id.view_5 })
List<View> mViews;
```

according to JakeWharton notes.

> use only R2 if you are making a library project.

also, make sure you inject your views `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

also, see this [tutorial](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) by jackWharton

Comment: sorry for bothering you but can  i have contact with you 'gmail' or any social network code is just messed up and need your help

Comment: bishoyabd@gmail.com -->  hangouts.